# $P(|X - 1| \geq 2)$ in terms of the distribution function $F_X$

Tags: probability, proof-verification

> Let $X$ be a random variable such that $P(|X - 1| = 2) = 0$. Express $P(|X - 1| \geq 2)$ in terms of the distribution function $F_X$.

My solution:

$P(|X -1| \geq 2) = 1 - P(|X - 1| \leq 2) = 1 - P(0 \leq X - 1 \leq 2) = 1 - P(1 \leq X \leq 3) $

$$ = 1 - (F_X(3) - F_X(1))$$

However I'm not certain if this is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You reached the correct answer but missed a few key facts.

1) $P[X\geq x]=1-P[X<x]$

So you have to put strict inequality instead of inequality in your 2nd step.

2) Use the fact that $P[|X-1|=2]=0$, it basically impies that $P[X=3]=0$ and $P[X=-1] =0$. So you have to use this to bring back the equality in the strict inequality as your second last step before claiming that the expression equals $1 - (F_X(3) - F_X(1))$ because by defination $F(x) = P[X\leq x]$ includes a equality sign in the inequality.

Answer (score 0):

You have picked the correct solution, however missed a small points. Let me rewrite it:
$$P(|X-1|\geq2) = 1-P(|X-1|<2) = 1 - P(-1< X <3) = 1 - (F_X(3) - F_X(-1) - P(X=3)) = 1 - F_X(3) + F_X(-1)$$
Because $P(X=3) = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Looks OK.. since $P(|X-1|=2)=0$, so $\ge $ vs. $\gt $ doesn't matter.